# How do I extract values and keys from a dictionary to be used to draw shapes and texts using ezgraphics?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary {'Malaysia': 529.0, 'China': 466.0, 'Scotland': 450.0, 'Japan': 391.0, 'France': 363.0} and I want to using ezgraphics to draw rectangles proportional to the values of each country. How do I extract the values to be used to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get values of a specific key from the dictionary use the following syntax:

```
countries = {'Malaysia': 529.0, 'China': 466.0, 'Scotland': 450.0, 'Japan': 391.0, 'France': 363.0}
malaysia_number = countries['Malaysia']
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it.